# cmake: stop if a manually specified variable is not used by the project

Tags: cmake

if I give as an input parameter an undefined variable to CMake, it will simply warn me about the fact that this variable is not used by the project.

So, I wonder whether one can tell cmake to stop in case of undefined variables given by the user.

The only approach I came so far to, was to parse the cmake output log and search for strings like:

```
CMake Warning:
Manually-specified variables were not used by the project
```

I had a look at the man of cmake, without finding something which could do the job.
so how can i tell cmake, that instead of a simple warning, that I may miss, it should stop on CMake Warning about unknown variables?

The solution, if any, should not involve modifying the CMakeList.txt files.

Of course, I can download the cmake sources and change in the

```
 cmake::RunCheckForUnusedVariables()
```

method:

```
 this->IssueMessage(cmake::WARNING, msg.str());
```

by:

```
 this->IssueMessage(cmake::FATAL_ERROR, msg.str());
```

but if i could avoid doing that hack, I will be grateful!

thanks for your help.

Comment: Would be more sensible to enable additional "modes" for `-Werror=...` so that you can use `--warn-unused-vars` and turn that into errors.